# jVector Map colors when displaying 2 datasets

Tags: jquery, angularjs, charts, jvectormap

I have 2 datasets- **ctrl.gdpData** and **ctrl.pdpData**, and I'm displaying them (on jVector world Map) like this-

```
$('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill',
        series: {
            regions: [{
            values: [ctrl.gdpData, ctrl.pdpData],
            scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        },
        onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
            el.html(el.html()+' (Deposit - '+ctrl.gdpData[code]+')'+' (Activation - '+ctrl.pdpData[code]+')');
            }
        });
```

The 'scale' that I used doesn't show any colors when I use the 2nd dataset also. I've tried using fill, backgroundcolor but none of them display the color that I want. Is there something that I'm missing? Is there a different way of displaying data from 2 datasets on the jVector world map?

PS- The display of data on the graph is perfect, no problems/errors there.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it myself, so I'll post the solution here.
This is the only thing that jVector Map uses for display of data-

```
el.html(el.html()+' (Deposit - '+ctrl.gdpData[code]+')'+' (Activation - '+ctrl.pdpData[code]+')');
```

So there is no need of supplying both the data sets at the 'values' attribute(also, this attribute only accepts only one). I changed it to-

```
values: ctrl.gdpData,
```

You just have to decide on which data set the map displays colors because as stated before 'values' attribute accepts only one data set.